# If $A$ has eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_k\}$ then does $A^n$ have only $\{\lambda^n_1,\lambda^n_2,...,\lambda^n_k\}$ as eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A$ has $k$ distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_k\}$ then does $A^n$ have only $\{\lambda^n_1,\lambda^n_2,...,\lambda^n_k\}$ as eigenvalues?

It is well know that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalues of $A$ then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalues of $A^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. But I am wondering whether $A^n$ has only $\lambda^n$ as eigenvalues, or are there more?

Comment: That is what I am asking @MathLover

Comment: We know that it must have at least $k$ distinct eigenvalues, but can there be more?

Answer (score 4):

Yes as long as it is diagonlizable.
$$A = P \Lambda P^{-1}$$
Then,
$$A^n = P \Lambda^n P^{-1}$$
I am not sure if that is possible in case it is not diagonlizable.

edit: it is possible even if not diagonlizable
$$Ax=\lambda x$$
$$AAx=\lambda Ax$$
$$A^2x=\lambda^2 x$$
and so on.

Comment: $A$ just need to be triangularizable

Comment: @Aaron: no. $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ is not diagonalizable over any field.  Presumably you mean "triangularizable".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes. That was a typo. Proof shows triangularizabolity (which is why the last word is triangular).  Will delete and repost with correction (since i'ts been too long to edit)

Comment: @Baconaro But over an algebraically closed field, every matrix is triangularizable. Indeed, Let $A:V\to V$. The characteristic equation of $A$ has at least one root, and hence we have at least one eigenvector $v$. Then $A$ descends to an endomorphism of $V/\mathbb kv$, and an induction on dimension of $V$ shows that $v$ is part of a basis in which $A$ is triangular.

Comment: @Baconaro according to the posted question $A$ has distinct eigen-values thus it is diagonlizable.